# Run-time error 91 Object Variable or With Block not Set

Tags: excel, vba, getopenfilename

I am getting this error

> Run Time Error '91' : Object Variable or With Block not Set.

What I am try to do is let user select files then select sheet3 (which name is Raw data) from selected files then copy to the current workbook

My code is

```
Private Sub OpenWorkBook_Click()

Dim myFile As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse your file", FileFilter:="Excel Files(*.xls*),*xls*")

If OpenBook <> False Then
    Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(myFile)
    OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(myFile)
    OpenBook.Sheets(3).Range("A1:3063").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw data(STEP 1)").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    OpenBook.Close False
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Highlighted line `If OpenBook <> False Then`

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be `If myFile <> False Then`. `myFile` is the variable you're using to get the file name. `OpenBook` isn't set until afterwards, hence the null error.

Comment: yeah it works thanks, but this line ```OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(myFile)``` give me error 424 object required is there anything wrongs with the code?

Comment: The code in your comment is missing `Set`. That would be required. It's there in your question, is it there in your actual code?

Comment: one more question, Why I am getting Runtime Error '1004'
on this line ```OpenBook.Sheets(3).Range("A1:3063").Copy```

Comment: Hi. In the range u are putting A1:3063.. You missed a letter...